# Can we use Ionic 1 plugin in Cordova project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, cordova-plugins

I am building a Cordova application and trying to use a plugin 
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks

But i am getting exception when i run my project. Can we use ionic plugin in crodova project?

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaDeeplinksProvider <- $cordovaDeeplinks
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaDeeplinksProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaDeeplinks
    at ionic.bundle.js:13443
    at ionic.bundle.js:17793
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17946)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17798
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17946)
    at injectionArgs (ionic.bundle.js:17970)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17992)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17808
    at forEach (ionic.bundle.js:13696)
    at createInjector (ionic.bundle.js:17808)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this plugin only if you are Ionic framework for developing cordova apps. Ionic framework is based on AngularJS but used Cordova framework as its base.Check out this [link](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/11/ionic-angularjs-framework-on-the-rise/) which elaborates more about Ionic framework.

If you are using vanilla cordova framework for app development, then you should use plugins like [universal link plugin](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin) or [custom URL scheme plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme) to achieve this as these [Ionic deep link plugin](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks) is evolved from these plugins using them as the base.

Hope it helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time on this problem i got to know that exception mentioned in the question is because of not absence of dependency. When i tried to use ionic plugin in cordova project, the ionic plugin had dependecy on ionic-native. Hence as rightly mentioned by @Gandhi we can not use ionic plugin in cordova project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. A step-by-step guide can be found [here](https://dev.to/hitman666/how-to-use-deep-linking-in-ionic-1-apps-with-ionic-native-deeplinks-plugin).

Please note that:

- Library `ionic-native` must be copied manually into your `lib` folder.
- A suffix is required to have the links correctly working when using parameters. As reported on the guide:

  > The most important part here, on which I've wasted most of the time is the nikola://app/chats/4 part. Namely, at first I expected that you only should write it as nikola://chats/4, but by finding the bug report about this in the official repo I realized that you have to put something as a suffix (I've put app here).